Spring Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
I have got a brand new Spring project from the Spring Initializr website. I selected only the WEB dependency.
When I try to run the project using the line mvn clean spring-boot:run I get this error.

I use Java 17, spring-boot-starter-parent 3.3.2 and Maven 3.9.8. Windows 10 x64.
What I have already tried:

Delete the .m2 folder (the same error remains);
Move the project folder to C:\ and run it the same way. Now I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.


pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

EDIT: I found out that when I change the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 3.3.x to 3.2.8 then spring runs successfully! But why the version 3.3.2 doesn't work for me even though when I delete the .m2 folder? Note that my Windows username consists of non-English characters (Russian). Is there a possibility that a bug has appeared in the versions 3.3.x which fails to handle such paths?

Can you show us the folder structure of your project and tell us from where you are running mvn clean spring-boot:run.  BR

@RoarS. It is a generated project from Spring Initializr. I run the command from the root of the project where pom.xml is stored.

The screenshot (by the way, please don't paste images of text) doesn't show any sign that your code was compiled; Maven seems to have tried to run it straight away. It's as if it thinks it's already up to date and therefore didn't bother compiling it.

@k314159 when I delete the target folder and run the program, it creates a new target folder and compiles every .java file to target/classes (according to the logs in cmd).

Does that target folder contain the file DemoApplication.class in the folder target/classes/com/example/demo?

@k314159 yes, it does.

Then it sounds like spring-boot:run is failing to set up the correct classpath.

@k314159 I think so too. I even tried running my old projects, which worked fine, but this error started appearing there too. Then I updated Maven and Spring Boot to the latest versions and nothing changed. Maybe something is not okay with my PC. I've been stuck on this problem for three days now.

Check if you've got some funny options in some environment variable.

It turns out I can use mvn package and then java -jar target/myapp.jar and it will work but it's not the solution because the application will take a long time to launch.

@k314159 no, there aren't any funny options. How "funny options" can affect only the spring-boot:run?

I was imagining some option that might affect the classpath. When using java -jar target/myapp.jar it's not affected by the classpath. You should be able to run the application without packaging: mvn assemble followed by java -cp target/classes com.example.demo.DemoApplication

@k314159 Hello. I found out that when I chnage the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 3.3.x to 3.2.8 then spring runs successfully. Can the reason be the cyrillic characters in my project path?

I doubt it: there must be a lot of Russian users of Spring Boot that would have had (and reported) the same issue. Have a look at What's New in 3.3 in case there's some breaking change.

@k314159 I created a new Windows user with a name in English and somehow it worked. I have no idea why 3.3.x doesn't work for the other Windows user with russian name.

@k314159 to be 100% sure I also created a new Windows user with russian name and Spring failed to run again. Check these: https://ibb.co/CsKLdfd https://ibb.co/QkYNnFD I think it's a bug or some kind of sanctions.

I doubt it's anything to do with sanctions, as Russian is not the only language that uses Cyrillic. Maybe try again with a user with a pure ASCII name.
